# What should be the value of ARGS in pyst2(python asterisk library)?

Tags: python, asterisk, agi, pyst

```
>>>from asterisk.agi import *
>>>agi = AGI() #after execute this, below thing poped
>>>ARGS: ['']

ENV LINE: 
>>>class AGI: self.env = {}
```

I just import pyst2's agi class and and after creating object of that class it is asking args and EVN, what are those?

I read pyst2 documents but nothing like this I found or maybe I missed.

I just need agi class so I didn't look into other parts of documents.

Maybe its something class parameter(not sure) but what if I just need to print my python variable using NoOp or verbose? still we need to use this?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk AGI interface is simple text protocol which operate with info from STDIN handle.

On script load you got arguments about script params, params are from dialplan AGI() call.

Protocol can't be functional without params about call, sorry.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-agi/